# How do i retrieve a JWT token from a Post response when using HttpClient

Tags: angular, jwt, angular5

I am trying to replace the use of `Http` with `HttpClient` in my login service.

When i used Http to get the token i could simply use `response.json().token` , But `HttpClient` has no json() method. I searched for the token in the headers of the post response but all i get are the keys, pragma, content-type and expires and they have no values.

The token is being sent by the server so thats not the problem, or else i wouldn't have gotten a token either when using the `http` approach. I looked for the token in the body of the response as well, but when i print the body out i get [Object object], body.toString() doesn't work either. Can anyone help? Heres my code:

```
  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post(this.authUrl, JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password}), {headers: this.headers, observe: 'response'}).map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            // let keys: string[] = response.body();
            // for( let i= 0; i < keys.length; i++){
            //   console.log("key: " + keys[i]) + " " + response.headers.get(keys[i]);
            // }
            let token: any = response.body;
            console.log("token is: " + token);
            if (token) {
                // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token }));
                this.loggedIn.next(true);
                // return true to indicate successful login
                return true;
            } else {
                // return false to indicate failed login
                return false;
            }
        }).catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

Comment: There is no longer any need to call `.json()`, because the response is already parsed for you. If you `console.log(response)`, you should see the parsed HTTP response body

Comment: yes, but then i see Object object printed out, not a token.

Comment: Use your debugger, or JSON.stringify the object before printing it, or go to the network panel of your browser dev tools, or read the source of your server code, or use `console.log("token is: ", token);` to know what the response contains.

Comment: Note that observing the response is counter-productive, since all you care about is the body. catching the error doesn't seem to serve any purpose either.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by using the pipe method (more info here: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/23/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial)

Heres the correct code.

```
  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.authUrl, JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password}), {headers: this.headers}).pipe(
      map((response:any) => {
            let token: any = response.token;
            if (token) {
                // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token }));
                this.loggedIn.next(true);
                // return true to indicate successful login
                return true;
            } else {
                // return false to indicate failed login
                return false;
            }
        }),
        catchError((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
      );
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't stringify your body. Angular does that for you. If the headers only contain the content-type , once again, this is useless: Angular adds that for you. Read the guide about HttpClient. It's also unclear why you use `any`rather than defining a proper interface describing what you're supposed to receive.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to access the response object, you need two changes,
in the server side put the token inside an array:

```
if(myuser.user_password!==userData.user_password){
                    res.status(401).send("Invalid password");
                }else{
                    let payload = { subject: myuser.user_login };
                    let token = jwt.sign(payload,"mySecretKey", {expiresIn: "15min"});
                    res.status(200).send([{ token, myuser }]); 
                }
```

then in the client side you will be able to access the array like this:

```
this.auth.getObject(this.form.value).subscribe(
      data=>{
        localStorage.setItem("token",data[0].token);
        this.router.navigate(["/home"], { skipLocationChange: true});
```

now you will have access to the token or any other data.